# Javascript insert array with null value into string

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to display the null element when concatenated to a string?

```
var arr = [];
arr.push('x');
arr.push(null);
arr.push('z');

// arr = ['x', null, 'z']

var samp = 'Array elements are: ' + arr;

// Array elements are: 'x',,'z'
```

Output that I want:

```
Array elements are: 'x', null,'z'
```

Comment: You can concatenate strings only. So check for `null` if it is null, create null as string "null" and then concatenate. null is a typeof object, so you can do JSON.stringify(null) which will be converted to string

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT - I'm trying to avoid inserting a "null" (as string) into the string as I also need this for SQL Queries where the queries can insert an actual string and an actual null value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can apply `String` to the arguments using Array.map. It's very succinct:

```
arr.map(String)
```

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push('x');
arr.push(null);
arr.push('z');

var samp = 'Array elements are: ' + arr.map(String);
console.log(samp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly coercing an array to a string calls the `.join` method, and:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

> If an element is undefined or null, it is converted to the empty string.

So, you can't use implicit coercion or `.join`. One option would be to use `reduce` to manually join every element (so as not to skip `null`s):

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push('x');
arr.push(null);
arr.push('z');


const joined = arr.reduce((a, elm) => a + (a ? ',' : '') + elm);

var samp = 'Array elements are: ' + joined;
console.log(samp);
```

If you also want the *quotes* around each string as with your

```
Array elements are: 'x', null,'z'
```

then check the `typeof` each element before concatenating:

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push('x');
arr.push(null);
arr.push('z');


const joined = arr.reduce((a, elm) => {
  const quote = typeof elm === 'string' ? "'" : '';
  return a + quote + (a ? ',' : '') + elm + quote;
}, '');

var samp = 'Array elements are: ' + joined;
console.log(samp);
```

(if the elements contain any single-quotes themselves, you may want to replace them with `\'` as well)

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` knows how to represent stuff in string form. If you just stringify your array, you get almost what you want:

```
JSON.stringify(arr)
# => ["x",null,"z"]
```

But if you do it yourself, you can avoid the square brackets, put a bit more space in...

```
arr.map(JSON.stringify).join(', ')
# => "x", null, "z"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an unusual yet interesting requirement.
The easy thing is that you want to display null as a part of the final string. So, here's what I tried:

```
function arrToStr(inputArr){ //this func will return str with null
var str=undefined;
inputArr.map(function(i){str = (str!==undefined) ? (str+", "+i) : i})
return str;
}

var arr = [];
arr.push('x');
arr.push(null);
arr.push('z');

var samp = 'Array elements are: ' + arrToStr(arr);
//samp - "Array elements are: x, null, z"
```

Hope you got the catch here?